# Error while trying out JUnit

Tags: java, weblogic, junit4

I have done more than an hour of searching while trying to run JUnit on my project. I can see that there is a class missing - `LogEntryFormatter`. But no matter how hard I tried, I am not able to find the jar file which contains this one. Eclipse shows the below stack trace after running the Test case file.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/logging/LogEntryFormatter
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass0(ClassLoader.java:892)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:302)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:300)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
>       at weblogic.logging.commons.LogImpl.(LogImpl.java:14)
>       at weblogic.logging.commons.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:21)
>       at weblogic.logging.commons.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:18)
>       at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:91)
>       ...

When I use `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` and if I use `@RunWith(JUnit4.class)`, a sample test seems to work.

Any sort of help will be useful. I am using WebLogic server, and all weblogic related jars are available on the classpath.

Comment: Consider using [TestNG](http://testng.org). Since you seem to be running a test framework for the first time, try this instead of JUnit. Made the switch, never looked back.

Comment: have you tried to force weblogic to use Log4j http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/logging/config_logs.html#using_log4j

Comment: I can see this class in my weblogic.jar which is in Weblogic 12.1  Are you using the same version? Check for the class in the JAR file

Comment: I added weblogic.jar, but getting the same error :(

Comment: you need to define some other commons logging implementation than weblogic one. No point in using weblogic logging for unit tests.

Comment: @eis, I understand that. I have just started writing JUnit. It would be helpful to know where to configure that.

Comment: is it a possibility to remove all the weblogic jars from classpath for tests?

Comment: I removed all weblogic jars from the classpath, and still only with junit4's jar on the classpath getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a lot of effort I am able to run JUnit Tests, although not in the exact way I want. I am also at a loss to explain why this is happening or where `weblogic.logging` is configured. This could be a possible problem with my project setup. After adding the following jar files to the classpath (after removing everything except jdk), it seems to be working for me.

- wlclient
- com.bea.core.utils.classloaders
- com.bea.core.descriptor
- com.bea.core.utils
- com.bea.core.management.core
- junit 4.5

Thanks to all those who helped by providing valuable comments. The stack traces encountered at each step helped me point in the right direction.